# Using javascript, how can i split list of email ids that has comma or "@"even in display name?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
var s = "'Jim,Rose'<jim@l.com>, 'John'<john@p.com>, 'jack@k.com'<jack@k.com>"
```

Comment: what is expected output from above data?

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume you have double quotes around that string:

```
var s = "'Jim,Rose'<jim@l.com>, 'John'<john@p.com>, 'jack@k.com'<jack@k.com>";
```

Then use the following regex to do a match:

```
var emails = s.match(/<.*?>/g);
```

Which produces this array:

```
["<jim@l.com>", "<john@p.com>", "<jack@k.com>"]
```

With a bit of trickery, you can get rid of the `<` and `>` as well:

```
emails = s.match(/<.*?>/g).join(',').replace(/<|>/g, '').split(',');
```

---

If in fact you wanted the "display names" instead, you can do a very similar operation with:

```
var names = s.match(/'.*?'/g);
```

Which would produce this array instead:

```
["'Jim,Rose'", "'John'", "'jack@k.com'"]
```

Comment: thanks.                                                            but i have email ids that don't have display name                  var s = 'Jim,Rose'<jim@l.com>, 'John'<john@p.com>, jack@k.com, "sony's"<sony@xyz.com>;

Answer (score 0):

Google's Closure library has the best solution for this I've seen.  See http://www.sbrian.com/2011/01/javascript-email-address-validation.html.  It's really easy to integrate the needed files.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something along these lines:

```
var s = "'Jim,Rose'<jim@l.com>, 'John'<john@p.com>, 'jack@k.com'<jack@k.com>";
matches = s.match(/'[^']+' *<[^>]+>/g);
```

This should work if all names are single-quoted. It's more complicated if you need to catch something like "Mike O'Niel" . To allow for that:

```
matches = s.match(/(['"]).+?\1 *<[^>]+>/g);
```